# How to save file in custom place in C

Tags: c

I'm working with C right now. And there's a problem. I don't know how to save a FILE in custom place. When I run *.exe file, it saves them where code is placed. So how to make it save FILEs where I want it to be?(I can input a path)

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Please share your code, it's impossible to refer to the question otherwise.

Comment: Include the code that saves a file. Do you understand about paths, for example: "C:\Some\Directory\Path\To\Myfile.txt" vs. "Myfile.txt"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a FILE is actually a long type that addresses a path on your computer.
Whether you use linux, windows, etc, the common thing about the paths is the idea that there are **relative** paths or **absolute** paths.

From what I've understood you probably did use the relative path, and I can guess you didn't specified a path at all, but only the file name. 
Notice that a **file's name alone is placed relatively** to the path of the program you are running.

To fix your problem you might want to give an absolute path (such as "/home/user/" on linux or "C:\Users\user" on windows [pay attention for the escaping backslash]).
You can do it by something like this:

```
FILE *output = fopen("/home/user/output.txt", "w");
```

(where "w" means writing permissions to the file at the given path).

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, I was on hackathon that day or solving challenge on some site.. I am sorry that I didn't respond on time, since this problem had something to do with time limit. Anyway, thank you for giving a detailed answer